# how to solve: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0

Tags: android, gradle

I had already upgraded to android x and my firebase messaging system worked for many days but now i get this error: 
''' 
`Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0`

''' 
[my error image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKpvI.jpg)

here is my full gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.esppad.fansy4"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material
    api group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.1.0-alpha09'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2")
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

what should I do for fixing the problem ?

Comment: tried but didnt worked. And also I tried 19.0.0

Comment: Don't mix **support** library with **AndroidX** library

Comment: still didn't workes

Comment: yess I changed Like that but problem is still there